# How to solve a system of matrices? (I do not mean solving a system thanks to matrices at all)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Here is my problem:

I have a sytem consisting of $2 \times 2$ matrices and I do not know what method to use to solve it.

Here is the system (excuse me for the clumsy notation)
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}  u  + \begin{bmatrix}3  & -3 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} v =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} u + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\1  & -1\end{bmatrix} v= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

What I thought of is to use inverses and come to $u+v = a$ matrix.

Is that right?

Thanks for the help

Comment: thanks, but I edited my question just now

Comment: For small matrices like this, you can just use matrix multiplication to write down scalar equations for vector components

Comment: actually I think this method is wrong and I don't think I can come to u+v=a matrix this way

Comment: so should I write u and v as $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Only different ones. You have four scalar unknowns

Comment: This is a linear system of four equations in four variables in disguise

Comment: $$Au+Bv=p,Cu+Dv=q \\ \iff \begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: but how can we put matrices inside of matrices @Rahul ??

Comment: Block matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix